# How to download images from an xml feed using terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, command-line, bash

How can I download png images from an xml feed that looks the following way?

```
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://url1.com">
  <Name>imagesToUse</Name>
<Prefix/>
<Marker/>
<IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
<Contents>
  <ImageStuff>imagetodownload.png</ImageStuff>
  <Size>17293</Size>
</Contents>
```

I was taking a look at [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80990/using-curl-to-download-images-in-xml-feed) on here about the same topic, except that I don't need to rename them, just download them.

Being new to shell scripts, I'm not quite sure how to do this (although I can definitely do this in 2 minutes in objective-c).

I have tried creating the following script and running `bash myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
URL='https://theurlwiththexml.com'
i=0
for u in $(curl -s "$URL" |
           grep png | 
           sed -E 's/.*<ImageStuff>(.+)<\/ImageStuff>/\1/'); do
    curl -s "$u" -o $i.png
    (( i++ ))
done
```

But nothing happens. It just prints another line without errors.

Answer (score 1):

After `curl http://theurlwiththexml.com`:

```
sed -n 's,.*<ImageStuff>\(.*\.png\)<.*,\1,p'|xargs -I, curl http://url1.com/, -o ,
```

`sed -n` disables printing, `\(` and `\)` are a portable way to specify groups, and `p` prints the pattern space. `xargs -I` specifies a replacement string and `curl -o` specifies an output file.

Or using `xmlstarlet`, `parallel`, and `wget`:

```
xml sel -t -v //ImageStuff|parallel wget http://url1.com/{}
```

`sel` is an abbreviation for `select`, `-t -v` uses the value template, and `//ImageStuff` is an XPath expression that matches all `ImageStuff` nodes.